# ls, regexp and environment variable

Tags: shell, wildcards

I wanted to declare an environment variable that stocks all the extensions of video files so I can use it when using the shell.

I tried several things but never got it to work:
If in my .bash_profile I put:

```
export VIDEOS={mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}
```

it only takes the last element:

```
[nbarraille@nbarraille ~]echo $VIDEOS
mpeg
```

If in my .bash_profile I put:

```
export VIDEOS="{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}"
```

or

```
export VIDEOS='{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}'
```

Then, when I display it it looks OK, but it doesn't work when I use it in a ls for example:

```
[nbarraille@nbarraille ~] echo $VIDEOS
{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}
[nbarraille@nbarraille ~] ll *.$VIDEOS
ls: cannot access *.{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}: No such file or directory
```

And when I run the exact same command without using the variable, it works:

```
[nbarraille@nbarraille ~] echo *.{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}
example.avi
example2.mpg
```

Also, when I reboot, it looks like my .bash_profile is not loading, and the $VIDEOS variable is empty. I have to do a `source ~/.bash_profile` in order to get it to work (and I have to redo so every time I open a new terminal.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your command is being expanded to this:

```
export VIDEOS=mp4 VIDEOS=wmv VIDEOS=avi VIDEOS=flv VIDEOS=mkv VIDEOS=m4u VIDEOS=mpg VIDEOS=mpeg
```

Run this to see what's happening:

```
echo export VIDEOS={mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}
```

(it's called [brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion))

---

The second problem is that `bash` does brace expansion before parameter expansion, not after it, so anything that looks like your solution will be messy.

You would have to do something like this:

```
eval echo \*.$VIDEOS
```

which will get annoying to type every time.

How about something like this:

```
videos() {
    find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f \
        \( -name "*.mp4" -o -name "*.wmv" -o -name "*.avi" -o \
           -name "*.flv" -o -name "*.mkv" -o -name "*.m4u" -o \
           -name "*.mpg" -o -name "*.mpeg" \)
}
```

Then instead of doing:

```
ls *.$VIDEOS
```

just do this:

```
videos
```

or if you need to pass it to a command:

```
ls $(videos)
```

---

This part working:

```
echo *.{mp4,wmv,avi,flv,mkv,m4u,mpg,mpeg}
```

could be the clue to `.bash_profile` not working.  For example, it might mean you are using `zsh`.

Please tell us what this does:

```
echo $0
```

so we can figure out which file you have to put it in.

Comment: echo $0 => /bin/bash

Comment: Well, then it either needs to go in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, depending on your setup.  Please try both.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your post it was useful. I will try to put it in .bashrc and I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably use arrays for this. Your syntax will have to be a bit different:

```
export VIDEOS=(.mp4 .wmv .avi .flv .mkv .m4u .mpg .mpeg)
```

and then do

```
ls ${VIDEOS[*]/./*.}
```

If you only want to list videos with names starting with `foo`, you would do

```
ls ${VIDEOS[*]/./foo*.}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about an alias or script?:

```
ls -m *.mp4 *.wmv *.avi *.flv *.mkv *.m4u *.mpg *.mpeg 2>/dev/null
```

name it `lvd` -- fewer characters (NB: `lv` is multilingual file viewer)